# how to create a JSON object in action class of JAVA

Tags: java, json, xstream

I want to create a JSON object. I have tried the following

```
myString=new JSONObject().put("JSON", sampleClass).toString();
```

but mystring gives me {"SampleClass@170f98"}.

I also tried the following

```
 XStream xsStream=new XStream(new JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver());
 SampleClass sampleClass=new SampleClass(userset.getId(),userset.getUsername());
 myString=xsStream.toXML(sampleClass);
```

It works but when i use getJSON in javascript to get myString it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
String myString = new JSONObject().put("JSON", new JSONObject(sampleClass)).toString();
```

in my instance it looks like this:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.Test;

public class JsonTest
{
    public static class SampleClass
    {
        private String id;

        private String userName;

        public SampleClass ( String id, String name )
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.userName = name;
        }

        public String getUserName ()
        {
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName ( String userName )
        {
            this.userName = userName;
        }

        public String getId ()
        {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId ( String id )
        {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testSampleClass () throws Exception
    {
        SampleClass sampleClass = new SampleClass ( "myId", "MyName" );
        System.out.println ( new JSONObject ( sampleClass ).toString () );
    }
}
```

the result looks like this:

```
{"userName":"MyName","id":"myId"}
```

Comment: The Constructor JSONObject(sampleClass) is undefined

Comment: I am getting the following error
A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of SampleClass@1385846
please help me to solve

Comment: no it isn't http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.Object)

Comment: you are sure that your toString() call is at the right place? Please post more of your code, in any other case it is just guessing.

Comment: Thanks its working now but how to use it in JSP page. iam using getJSON in javascript but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
XStream xsStream=new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into GSON, a Java Library for converting Objects to JSON by Google.  [GSON Library][1]

From the Google Code site:

> http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

- Provide simple toJson() and fromJson() methods to convert Java objects to JSON and vice-versa
- Allow pre-existing unmodifiable objects to be converted to and from JSON